# Issue with CSS file loader of Elementor wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am having the following issue in my log file :

```
script_filename = /code//index.php
[0x00007f78a8017e10] Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\{closure}() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:342
[0x00007f78a8017d90] preg_replace_callback() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:342
[0x00007f78a8017b80] add_control_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:670
[0x00007f78a8017ad0] add_control_style_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:539
[0x00007f78a80179c0] add_controls_stack_style_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:222
[0x00007f78a80178e0] add_controls_stack_style_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:298
[0x00007f78a8017850] render_styles() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:226
[0x00007f78a8017770] add_controls_stack_style_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:298
[0x00007f78a80176e0] render_styles() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:226
[0x00007f78a8017600] add_controls_stack_style_rules() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:298
[0x00007f78a8017570] render_styles() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/post.php:178
[0x00007f78a80174c0] render_css() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:632
[0x00007f78a8017420] parse_content() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/base.php:155
[0x00007f78a80173c0] get_content() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php:278
[0x00007f78a8017350] print_css() /code/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php:1089
[0x00007f78a8017280] get_builder_content() /code/wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/components/cpt/layouts/layouts-sc-elementor.php:337
[0x00007f78a8017190] trx_addons_cpt_layouts_elm_layout_content() /code/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292
[0x00007f78a80170b0] apply_filters() /code/wp-includes/plugin.php:212
[0x00007f78a8016fe0] apply_filters() /code/wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/components/cpt/layouts/layouts.php:565
[0x00007f78a8016ed0] trx_addons_cpt_layouts_show_layout() /code/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292
```

I believe there is a change that needs to be applied to the Elementor Wordpress plugin but I am unable to fix it or find any good documentation.

Is there any body who has faced this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: If a specific plugin doesn't work as it should, it's probably better to contact the developers of the plugin. We are not them. Also, the tag `element` is not referring to the plugin `elementor`. Two completely different things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hope to find someone who got the same issue as I did not find support.